# Only update controls in same row in ItemTemplate, ListView

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, listview, c#-4.0

I currently have the following ListView displayed.

[image]

The "SI Number" is Databound, and on SelectedIndex_Changed, the "Job Number" is binded and the same for ProductDescription.

If I select an "SI Number" in the "Labelling Line 1" line, all of the "Job Number" dropdowns are populated.

How can I avoid this?

Below is my ItemTemplate source:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" class='<%# ConditionalString(Eval("LineID"), "", "-memo-row-inactive") %>'>
        <td style="padding: 0px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPIncludeLine" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludeLine" ToolTip='<%# Eval("LineID") %>' runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("LineDesc") %>' Checked='<%# IsProductionLineSelected(Eval("LineID")) %>'
                        Font-Bold='<%# IsProductionLineSelected(Eval("LineID")) %>' CssClass="-memo-checkbox"
                        AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkIncludeLine_OnCheckedChanged" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkIncludeLine" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
        <td class="-field-inactive" align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLineID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LineID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td class="-field-inactive" align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="ProductionTypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# TranslateSizeCode(Eval("ProductionType")) %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0px;">
            <asp:DropDownList Width="160px" ID="ddlSINumber" runat="server" DataSourceID="ActiveSalesInstructionsData"
             DataTextField="SalesInstructionNumber" DataValueField="SalesInstructionNumber" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSINumber_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </td>
        <td class="-field-status" style="padding: 0px;">
            <asp:DropDownList Width="160px" ID="ddlJobs" DataSourceID="LabelingJobData"
             DataValueField="Job" DataTextField="Job" runat="server">

             </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0px;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlProductDesc" CssClass="-clip" Width="200px" Visible="false" runat="server" >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductDesc" runat="server" CssClass="-memo-inactive-display-label"
                        Text='<%# GetProductName(Eval("LineID")) %>'></asp:Label>
                        <!--!IsProductionLineSelected(Eval("LineID"))-->
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPProductCode" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lsProductCode" Width="100%" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="LabelingJobData"
                            DataTextField="StockCode" DataValueField="StockCode" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lsShippingID_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                            runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lsProductCode" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my SelectedIndexChanged:

```
protected void ddlSINumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        var selectedSI = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
        hvSalesInstructionNumber.Value = selectedSI;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hvSalesInstructionNumber.Value))
        {
            var control = (DropDownList)ddl.Parent.FindControl("ddlJobs");
            control.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

On Control.DataBind, I bind the DropDownList to a SqlDataSource.

Comment: What does your `ddlSINumber_SelectedIndexChanged` event look like?

Comment: I have added the SelectedIndexChanged to my original post.

Comment: Is `hvSalesInstructionNumber.Value` a parameter to your DataSource or something?

Comment: That is correct yes. It is a hiddenField which is used as a parameter in the Datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your DataSource like you are: `DataSourceID="LabelingJobData"`, you are setting that source for every `ddlJobs` DropDownList in the ListView.

[ObjectDataSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource(v=vs.110).aspx) also auto-bind on every page load, unless explicitly cancelled.

> If you set the DataSourceID property of a data-bound control, the
>   control automatically binds to data from the data source, as needed.
>   Setting the DataSourceID property is the recommended method for
>   binding an ObjectDataSource control to a data-bound control.
>   Alternatively, you can set the DataSource property, but then you must
>   explicitly call the DataBind method of the data-bound control. You can
>   call the Select method programmatically at any time to retrieve data.

Because of this, as soon as you set the parameter value for your DataSource, it binds each `ddlJobs` DropDownList automatically. You wouldn't have to call DataBind().

To get around this, I would suggest not using the `DataSourceID` in the markup, but to instead set the `DataSource` in the codebehind and only bind it for one specific control.

```
protected void ddlSINumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    string selectedSI = ddl.SelectedValue;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSI))
    {
        DropDownList control = (DropDownList)ddl.Parent.FindControl("ddlJobs");
        control.DataSource = YourGetterMethod(selectedSI);
        control.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.  I have removed the DataSourceID property, and within the SelectedIndexChanged, I retrieved the row number, and used the row number to get the control I would like to Databind from the ItemTemplate row, and bind it in the CodeBehind file.  Thank you for taking the time to help me with this.